# How to redirect root to subdirectory while maintaining URL in the address bar

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, url

I have an nginx setup with folder structure like this:

```
- www
  |- splash
  |- blog
```

`www` is the root folder.

I would like to redirect users who access `http://example.com` to the `splash` folder.

But I don't want the URL in the address bar to change to `http://example.com/splash`.

The URL in the address bar should still be `http://example.com`.

This rule should only apply when user accesses the root folder.

Meanwhile accessing the `blog` folder will be as usual via: `http://example.com/blog`.

How do I achieve this? So far my conf is as follow: (they don't work btw, the URL is changed)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /www;
        location = / {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ splash/$1 permanent;
        }
}
```

Comment: I would use the last rewrite in the location block. I have the complete NGINX setup running at : https://thinapps.org/fiddle/iplcgyja46589edurdlcswonderquest have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Each context can have its own root.

Since you have a `location` context, just change the root.

Eg.

```
location = / {
    root /www/splash;
}
```

Documentation is available [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root). The example given in the documentation is:

```
location  /i/ {
  root  /spool/w3;
}
```

> A request for "/i/top.gif" will return the file "/spool/w3/i/top.gif".

So essentially, almost a copy of that, except you have the `=` for an exact match in location.

---

If there is a file called /splash/blog, do you want that url to go to /splash/blog or /blog?

Another way to prioritize files is using `try_files`. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files /splash/$uri $uri =404;
}
```

In this case, if there is a matching file in /splash, that's what will be shown, otherwise $uri is shown instead, or in the last case, a 404 error.

Comment: I've tried this scenario, but in this case if I add more folders in the root in the future, I have to manually update the config.

Can I somehow set it that if `/` then set root to `somefolder`. And else, set root to `anotherfolder`?

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me if I got your situation right:

```
location ~/splash.* {
    return 200 "The request was $uri";
}

location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /splash/ last;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

From [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)

> last
>       stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed
>   URI;

I didn't want to create directory /splash/ so I just told Nginx to respond with hardcoded text. You may replace it with required directives.

Answer (score 0):

That's all ...

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.com;
        root /www;

        location = / {
                root /www/splash;
        }

        location / {
                root /www;
        }


}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Accessing `http://mysite.com` still sees the content of `/www`. Any other ideas?

Comment: show your full config, please